# Python - solving for risk budget portfolio using cvxpy

Tags: python, portfolio, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I'm looking to write a set of code that allows me to set risk budget constraints to individual positions in a portfolio, i.e. each position to contribute a set amount of risk to the portfolio, and I'm looking to do it specifically in CVXPY as I have noticed sometimes SCIPY breaks the constraints.

I have the below code, I was wondering if you would be able to provide me with some direction as I have encountered cvxpy "The objective is not DCP" error and I'm not sure how to correct it.

Please also let me know if I should rephrase my question to make it clearer.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
# covmat is a (31,31) numpy array, covariance matrix calculated from monthly returns
risk_budget = np.repeat(1/31, 31).reshape(-1,1)
def risk_budget_objective(risk_budget, covmat):
    n =  covmat.shape[0]
    # set equal weight
    equal_wts = np.repeat(1 / n, n)

    # weights vertical
    wts = cp.Variable((n,1))
    constraints = [cp.sum(wts) == 1.0] # weight constraints

    port_variance = cp.square(cp.quad_form(wts, covmat)) # portfolio variance, not volatility
    mrc = covmat @ wts * 12 # vector # marginal risk contribution annualised
    risk_contrib = cp.multiply(mrc, wts) / port_variance # calculate risk contribution

    mean_square_diff = cp.sum(cp.square(risk_contrib - risk_budget)) #  squared difference and summed
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(mean_square_diff), constraints) # minimise squared difference
    prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS)
    if problem.status not in ["infeasible", "unbounded"]:
        solution = wts.value
        return solution
    else:
        print('Problem not feasible... resorting to equal weight...')
        return equal_wts
```

Looking into the objects, it seems that the problem lies in the following code:

`risk_contrib = cp.multiply(mrc, wts) / port_variance`

As the curvature is "UNKOWN" rather than convex.

Comment: This model is non-convex. CVXPY is for convex models only.

Comment: Are you refer to risk budgeting problem itself? or the code that I have produced?

Comment: Minimizing risk is convex. What you do is not.

Comment: This is a rather frequently asked question, but unfortunately the risk contribution is non-convex and cannot be expressed in cvxpy. (Already the part with multiply(mrc, wts) is problematic, dividing by port_variance only makes it worse).

Comment: I have faced the same problem, anyone has any ideas about solving this problem? thx in advance